# How can I store data from two different cell arrays into one structure field in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

This is my first one:

Assume I have a struct

```
student_information=struct{'name','','surnames,''};
```

and two cell arrays

```
possible_names=cell{'John','Amy','Paul'};
possible_surnames=cell{'Mitchell','Gordon','Maxwell'};
```

I need to fill the struct field 'name' with random names from the possible_names cell array which i figured:

```
for i=1:length(student_information)
 for j=1:length(possible_names);
 student_information(i).name=possible_names(randperm(j,1));
 end
end
```

But i need to fill the struct field 'surnames' with TWO random surnames (i.e "Gordon Maxwell") from the possible_surnames cell array... I tried a simmilar way to the method i used to fill the 'names' field but i didnt.

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense TBH.  You have a few syntax errors.  Specifically:

```
student_information=struct{'name','','surnames,''};
```

`'surnames'` needs an ending quotation.  This also only allocates **one** structure.  Also, `struct` is a function yet you are trying to use it like a cell array. You probably meant this:

```
student_information=struct('name','','surnames','');
```

On top of this:

```
possible_names=cell{'John','Amy','Paul'};

possible_surnames=cell{'Mitchell','Gordon','Maxwell'};
```

This is invalid MATLAB syntax.  `cell` is a function, yet you are trying to reference it as if it were a `cell` array.  Do this instead:

```
possible_names={'John','Amy','Paul'};
possible_surnames={'Mitchell','Gordon','Maxwell'};
```

Now, back to your code.  Judging from your context, you want to select two random names from `possible_surnames` and concatenate these into a single string.  Use `randperm` but generate **two** choices instead of 1 like in your code.  Next, you can cheat a bit by using `sprintf` and separating each name with a space:

```
possible_surnames={'Mitchell','Gordon','Maxwell'};
names = possible_surnames(randperm(numel(possible_surnames),2));
out = sprintf('%s ', names{:})

out =

Gordon Maxwell
```

As such, as you're populating your cell array, you can choose one random name from the `possible_names` array like so.  First you need to allocate the structure properly with a given number of slots:

```
student_information=struct('name','','surnames','');
student_information=repmat(student_information, 5, 1); %// Make a 5 element structure

possible_names={'John','Amy','Paul'};
for idx = 1 : numel(student_information)
    student_information(idx).name = possible_names{randperm(numel(possible_names), 1)};
end
```

Now for the `possible_surnames`, do:

```
possible_surnames={'Mitchell','Gordon','Maxwell'};
for idx = 1 : numel(student_information)
    names = possible_surnames(randperm(numel(possible_surnames),2));
    student_information(idx).surnames = sprintf('%s ', names{:});
end
```

Let's see what this structure looks like now:

```
cellData = struct2cell(student_information);
fprintf('Name: %s. Surnames: %s\n', cellData{:})

Name: Paul. Surnames: Maxwell Gordon 
Name: Amy. Surnames: Mitchell Maxwell 
Name: Paul. Surnames: Mitchell Gordon 
Name: John. Surnames: Gordon Maxwell 
Name: John. Surnames: Gordon Mitchell
```

Comment: rayryeng: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much for such a fast and excellent response.